# How can I simultaneously play Spotify audio through my headphone-out while VLC plays audio through HDMI?

Tags: 14.04, sound, hdmi, vlc, spotify

How can I setup Ubuntu such that it can play VLC audio through HDMI connected to a TV, but at the same time, it can also play music from Spotify via the headphones?

I'm running 14.04

Comment: You will only be able to do this if you have a dedicated sound card (so one for the HDMI output and another for the headphones). It then depends on your setup, but it can be rather 'complex' but once working very cool to show off.

Answer (score 2):

You can install and use [Pulseaudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/)[image: ubuntu software centre logo]. Go to the Ubuntu Software Centre and search for `pavucontrol`:
[image: pavucontrol in Ubuntu software centre]

Or use the following command in your cli:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Now start pavucontrol from the Ubuntu Dash (not the sound icon):

[image]

And select the desired output device under playback:[image: playback]

Happy listening!

Comment: Here's what I'm seeing [PulseAudio](http://i.imgur.com/1fzuUjk.png) I don't have that selection option beside the speaker button where you can choose the output device for the specific application...

Comment: When I go to the "Output Devices" tab, I only see the HDMI device [Output Devices screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/6y5ygq6.png) but when I go to System Settings ---> Sound, I see both the HDMI out and the built-in Speaker out [Sound Settings](http://i.imgur.com/bR2uhSG.png)

Comment: That is very strange, unfortunately I don't know enough about PulseAudio to tell you why your other output devices are missing.